# PHPMailer addAttachment only on Address not BCC

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working with phpmailer and emails are working great but and had no problem with the `$mail->addAttachment()` but I have a question.

I'm sending emails to the required address but also to myself as **blind copy**. The point is that attachments are being sent to both but I don't want to receive the attachment as well.

Is there any way to do this? Sending attachment to everyone except **blind copys**?

Comment: Send two emails instead of using bcc ?

Comment: That's a solution but not the one I want. I don't even know if this is even possible but if it is I'll be glad to know how. But thanks for your suggestion anyway! @DamirKasipovic

Comment: It may not be the answer you want, but it's the only one you're going to get; it's not possible to send different messages in one go; send two.

Comment: I've been looking for an answer and you're right. The only way is to set two different emails. Thanks for your time anyway! @Synchro